# Positioning of items when repeatedly pasting in Keynote

Tags: macos, keynote, copy-paste

Keynote has a really nice feature that I often use. If I (1) copy a shape, (2) paste it, (3) position the pasted item one centimetre to the right of the original (for example), and then (4) press CMD-V again, a new copy of the item will appear one centimetre to the right of the copy. This is great, because it makes it easy to make a nice line of copies with even spacing...

...except that it only happens about half the time. The rest of the time, pressing CMD-V a second time will produce a new copy in a different, unpredictable location. Clearly there's something that I'm doing differently in these cases, but I can't work out what it is.

Does anyone know if this feature has a name, and whether there's any specific instructions for activating it? I know there are other options for creating aligned copies of an object (e.g. `Arrange -> Align Objects`), but I find this way to be a particularly useful one.